# In Doctrine DBAL, how can I "stream" a query, avoid loading all the result filling the entire memory?

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine, dbal

I have a very large table and I don't want to fetch all the result. I want to fetch one result at time and take the advance of PHP generators. I can't find many information about fetching a result at time, and most of the examples use **old and deprecated methods**.

Is the following example "right" or I'm still fetching all the records with `executeQuery`?

```php
$query = ($qb = $this->connection->createQueryBuilder())
    ->select('*')
    ->from('users')
    ->where($qb->expr()->eq('enabled', ':enabled'))
    ->setParameter('enabled', true)
;

$stmt = $this->connection->executeQuery($query->getSQL(), $query->getParameters());
while ($row = $stmt->fetchAssociative()) {
    yield $row;
}
```

Comment: Try something like https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.16/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-large-results-for-data-processing

Comment: @u_mulder I'm using DBAL, not ORM but thanks.

Comment: Not sure it will help, but maybe you could use caching features : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/4.0/reference/caching.html